# Merge Eager Loading Result

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

i want try to merge a result from eager loading:

Here is my result:

```
 [{"id":3,"name":"John","email":"john@doe.com","username":"johndoe",
 "user_detail":{"address":"anywhere in the world","country":"Somewhere","city":"Somecity","phones":"012-12345","logo":"cute.jpg","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}}]
```

what i want to achieve is delete the user detail and join all the json become one like this:

```
 [{"id":3,"name":"John","email":"john@doe.com","username":"johndoe","address":"anywhere in the world","country":"Somewhere","city":"Somecity","phones":"012-12345","logo":"cute.jpg","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
```

My model:

```
/*User Model*/ 
public function user_detail(){
  return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
}

/*User Detail Model*/ 
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

My Controller:

```
$user= User::with('user_detail')->where('username', $username)->get();
```

Is there any function to merge the json become one?.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is array flattening. You can do it like this

```
    function flatten(array $array) { 
        $return = array(); 
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($a,$b) use (&$return) { $return[$b] = $a; }); 
        return $return; 
    }
```

and then call this function something like this(Use proper syntax for calling the function if its in the class)

```
$user= User::with('user_detail')->where('username', $username)->get();
$result = flatten($user);
```

This will give you the desired result. 
Hope this helps!